# Writing text within my three "DIV ID'S" displaces the boxes. (1PX SOLID BLACK)

Tags: html, css

I think the margins are causing an issue but I am not certain at this point. Have been trying for the last two hours. It only occurs with the three centered divs. Top videos, articles and photos. The rest are fine when I type text into them. When I do type text into them it displaces them vertically to the bottom just above the footer.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="page">
        <header></header>
                <div id="dog logo">
            </div>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photographs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div id="hero"><h1><b>HERO</b></h1></div>

    <div id="topvideo"></div>

    <div id="topphoto"></div>

    <div id="toparticles"></div>

    <div id="content"><h1><b>CONTENT</b></h1></div>

    <div id="footer"><h1><b>FOOTER</b></h1></div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
       #page {
        max-width: 850px;
        min-width: 840px;
        min-height: 1550px;
        max-height: 1600px;


    }

    ul {
        width: 813px;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
        border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
        display:inline-block;


    }

    li {
        display: inline;
        text-decoration: none;



    }

    #hero {
        width: 813px;
        height: 408px;
        border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px; (is it a problem with the margins>
        text-align: center;

    }

        #topvideo { **THIS DISPLACES**
        width: 267px;
        height: 370px;
        border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;



    }

        #topphoto { T**HIS DISPLACES**
        width: 267px;
        height: 370px;
        border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px; Could it be a problem with the margins?

    }

       #toparticles { **THIS DISPLACES**
        width: 267px;
        height: 370px;
        border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    }

    #content {
        width: 813px;
        height: 310px;
        border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
        margin: -5px 0px 0px 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #footer {

        width: 813px;
        height: 100px;
        border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
        border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
        margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
        text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Add `vertical-align:top` to the divs since they are `inline-block`.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Could you explain a little bit more to how it worked? Sorry, just really want to learn :)

Comment: inline block elements have a default alignment of `baseline` so they will line up according to the 'middle' of the contents. It;s a little complicated but setting it to `top` usually does the trick [**Vertical Align @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)